# UWP Xamarin C# - WebView go back navigation return page expired

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, uwp

the app show a site with the WebView.
The site site had a go back button to navigate but it show this error when i tap on it:

> **The web page has expired.** Main reason: the copy of the page on the phone is not updated and the site requests to update to see the
>   information

My WebView  request code:

```
var request = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("http://example.com/index.php"));

IHttpContent content = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(new [] { (new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param", myParam)) });
request.Content = content;
webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(request);
```

I had a similar problem on Xamarin.Android app and i resolved adding this code to WebView:

```
webView.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.Settings.SetAppCacheMaxSize(8 * 1024 * 1024);
webView.Settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.CacheElseNetwork;
```

I tried to see a similar configuration for UWP but I didn't find anything about it.

Can someone help me? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved adding this line of code and changing webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(request) to webView.Navigate(uri):

```
                var myFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
                myFilter.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                myFilter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior.Default;
                myFilter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.Default;
                var cookieManager = myFilter.CookieManager;

                var request = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("http://example.com/index.php"));
                IHttpContent content = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(new [] { (new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param", myParam)) });
                request.Content = content;

                using (var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
                {
                    var result = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
                    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    var resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }

                webView.Settings.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webView.Settings.IsIndexedDBEnabled = true;

                webView.Navigate(new Uri("http://example.com/index.php"));
```

Link to -> https://dzone.com/articles/sharing-sessions-between-httpclient-and-webviews-o